# How one can make an svg graphic with LaTeX text so that the text remains selectable?

Tags: text, svg, latex

I read a paper on robotics, it had some nice pictures with the schematic representation of an articulated robot. The special thing about it was that the forces and some other things are selectable on the picture. I selected several things in the picture below for the demonstration.

[image]

I don't have the source code of the paper. It's just my guess that the image was made as an `svg` with the selectable text.

Anyway. I tried to do something similar myself. Drawn an image in Incscape, installed TexText extension for it, wrote some text in LaTeX and added it. However, after I've added the LaTeX text, it was already not selectable. More precisely, it was added as grouped primitives. Besides `TexText` extension I also tried `pdflatex` (Extensions -> Render -> Formula (pdflatex)).

Can someone maybe share how they make `.svg` images for their `.tex` documents on which the text remains selectable? Is there maybe a special extension for Incscape that makes text objects from LaTeX formulae and not primitives? I am using Incscape 1.2.

Comment: Hi. Only SVG text elements are selectable in an SVG when viewed in Inkscape.  If the TexTex Extension doesn't actually create these but creates outlines (i.e. SVG paths), then as far as I know, there is no way to convert them to text elements other than by retyping them with the Text tool in Inkscape.

Comment: Well that's a pity. Do you know any other extensions that create text objects from the LaTeX commands?

Comment: I don't unfortunately.  I wonder if you would be better to ask this on TeX Stack Exchange. Somebody there may have an idea.

Comment: Ok. Originally, I wrote the question there and then decided it was more graphic design related.